# Launching Matlab from java ProcessBuilder, Matlab console doesn't appear in Mac OS 10.8

Tags: java, matlab, osx-mountain-lion, processbuilder

This is a really bizarre application, so bear with me.  The primary application consists of a Matlab back-end with a UI written in Java Swing.  To launch the application, you do something like the following from the command-line:

```
matlab -r "initMatlab;runJavaUI;"
```

Assume that `initMatlab` and `runJavaUI` are both Matlab functions on the path of the matlab runtime that gets spawned as a result of that command.  This basically spawns an instance of matlab, then runs those two matlab functions immediately after matlab starts.  The weird thing is, this command-line option doesn't work on all OSes.  Furthermore, not all versions of Matlab are compatible with all versions of Java (our customer wants to use REALLY old Matlab installs...  can't make 'em change it).

So ... we provide a Java executable Jar that automatically generates the command line arguments based on which OS you're running in - the user just double-clicks it to bring up a small UI, then is presented with a few options.  I'll call this jar the ***Launcher***.  This *Launcher* detects all installed instances of Java and Matlab and allows the user to pick which combination of Java and Matlab will get used.  The jar uses `ProcessBuilder` to launch the matlab command, which works fine, save for one thing.  In *Windows*, the *Launcher* starts Matlab just fine, we see the Matlab console appear, then the Java UI appears as it should.  However, on a Mac running Mountain Lion (10.8, I believe), the Matlab console never appears - this isn't to say that Matlab isn't running though - I can still make Matlab calls from the Java UI.  This doesn't prevent the user from using the UI, but sometimes Matlab will dump error messages to the console which is problematic, because on a Mac, the user will never know when something is going wrong.  The weirdest thing is, I have tried printing out the generated command line, which doesn't spawn the Matlab console when launched via `ProcessBuilder`, but **does** spawn the Matlab console when launched via terminal.  Once again, **Matlab isn't failing to start, it's failing to make its own UI visible.**

I have tried copying all of the *Launcher*'s environment variables into the `ProcessBuilder` prior to launching Matlab, to no avail.  So I have to leave this a bit open-ended, but **has anyone tried running Matlab using `ProcessBuilder`, and if so, what did you do to get the Matlab console to appear on Mac OS Mountain Lion?**

**SSCCE**

Export this code into a runnable jar file, then run the following on Mac OS Mountain Lion:

```
java -jar launch-matlab.jar /absolute/path/to/matlab
```

You should see the Matlab icon appear in the dock, but you won't be able to make the Matlab console window visible.  If you run this in Windows, the Matlab console appears as it should.

```
public class LaunchMatlab {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String matlabExe = "matlab";
        if(args != null && args.length > 0) matlabExe = args[0];
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        pb.command(matlabExe,"-wait");
        pb.environment().putAll(System.getenv());
        System.err.println("Launching Matlab using following PB args: "+
                pb.command());
        Process p = pb.start();
        System.err.println("Waiting for Matlab to exit ...");
        p.waitFor();
        System.err.println("Matlab exited, launcher exiting ...");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and continue to build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces. 2) Failing that, prepare and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  *"the code used to generate this command is very long"* hard code it for one example.

Comment: I think you don't understand the question, which is partly my fault for not being 100% clear.  `ProcessBuilder` isn't failing to launch Matlab, nor is the child process hanging - Matlab is failing to make its own UI visible.  I know that Matlab is running because it shows up in the Dock on Mac and I can make Matlab calls on the new Matlab instance from the Java UI.  I've already broken up the args in to String[], so that's also not a concern.  I'll try to come up with an SSCCE next.

Comment: SSCCE has been posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify that MATLAB is to run with a visible UI by making use of the `-desktop` flag. I don't believe this is documented.

So the command you need to run is

```
matlab -desktop -r "initMatlab;runJavaUI;"
```

I've created a Java library called [matlabcontrol](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com) that can abstract all of this away from you. It can launch MATLAB while running on Windows, OS X, and Linux and then allow you to interact with MATLAB via eval and feval commands. matlabcontrol's code to launch MATLAB is located in [matlabcontrol.RemoteMatlabProxyFactory](https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/source/browse/branches/4.1.0/matlabcontrol/src/matlabcontrol/RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.java)'s `createProcess(...)` method. If you make use of matlabcontrol as a Java library you won't directly interact with either this class or this method.

Comment: +1. Worth mentioning that using matlabcontrol as a Java library involves using the undocumented [jmi](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jmi-java-to-matlab-interface/) interface

Comment: Yep, this did the trick!  And I have been using matlabcontrol.  Seems silly that the default behavior is to not run the Matlab desktop on a Mac (isn't that what 99% of people who use Matlab want to do???), but sure enough ...  thanks again!